# Can't Import Python File - MNIST TO USPS - Google Pixel DA

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, bazel, usps

Currently attempting to run Google's Pixel Level Domain Adaptation Model. We were able to run MNIST to MNIST-M training and testing. Added the USPS tfrecords in the datasets folder and we recreated the MNIST_M.py file into a USPS.py file. Imported the filed like they import it for MNIST. Somehow when we run training, the architecture isn't able to find the USPS file.

Google's Original Model: [Google's Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/domain_adaptation)

Command being run:

```
bazel run domain_daptation/pixel_domain_adaptation:pixeldatrain -- --dataset_dir $DSN_DATA_DIR --source_dataset mnist --target_dataset usps
```

Location of usps.py file:

/home/.../models/domain_adaptation/datasets:usps
Original Stack Trace:

```
INFO: Analysed target //domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation:pixelda_train (2 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation:pixelda_train up-to-date:
bazel-bin/domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation/pixelda_train
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.575s, Critical Path: 0.12s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action

INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation/pixelda_train --dataset_dir /home/gabe/models/domain_adaptation/datasets --source_dataset mnist --target_dataset usps
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/.../.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/b15fa6ac5bc49187f8190f3d0425c8db/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation/pixelda_train.runfiles/__main__/domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation/pixelda_train.py", line 24, in <module>
from domain_adaptation.datasets import dataset_factory
File "/home/.../.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/b15fa6ac5bc49187f8190f3d0425c8db/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation/pixelda_train.runfiles/__main__/domain_adaptation/datasets/dataset_factory.py", line 26, in <module>
from domain_adaptation.datasets import usps
ImportError: cannot import name usps
ERROR: Non-zero return code '1' from command: Process exited with status 1
```

After following one of the users advice of adding location to the domain_adaptation/datasets/build. I ran the same command again.

```
py_library(
    name = "dataset_factory",
    srcs = ["dataset_factory.py"],
    deps = [
        ":usps",
        "//slim:mnist",
        ],
)
```

New Stack Trace:

```
ERROR: /home/.../models/domain_adaptation/datasets/BUILD:23:12: in deps              attribute of py_library rule //domain_adaptation/datasets:dataset_factory: rule '//domain_adaptation/datasets:usps' does not exist
ERROR: Analysis of target '//domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation:pixelda_train' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//domain_adaptation/datasets:dataset_factory' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.219s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target
```

Comment: Could you include the error / stack trace?

Comment: @AllenLavoie added stack trace

Comment: Maybe due to Bazel's hermeticity? I'd try adding the new usps.py file to domain_adaptation/datasets/BUILD, the dataset_factory rule.